# How do I work with a rails 4 collection and determine an object count by enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I have a Rails 4 app, where a User owns a Sales_Opportunity, and each Sales_Opportunity can have a "pipeline_status" which is implemented currently as an enum. This works fine, but now I am trying to create a user display that shows each of these pipeline_status(es) in a graphical manner (a series of chevrons that lead from "prospect" to "closed_won") and I want to display a badge on each chevron that shows the number of opportunities that user has within each pipeline_status.

I was trying to use the count method in rails, and pass in some conditions - but whilst this tells me how many Sales_Opportunities a User has (in total), it will not accept the condition argument and filter the count depending on the enum I pass. Can anyone help or point me toward a resource that can help me learn the right way to use this please?

Sales_Opportunity.rb:

```
class SalesOpportunity < ActiveRecord::Base
default_scope { order('close_date ASC') }
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :company
has_many :timeline_events, dependent: :destroy
has_many :swots, dependent: :destroy
validates :close_date, presence: true
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :company_id, presence: true
validates :opportunity_name, presence: true
enum pipeline_status: [ :prospect, :qualifying, :demonstrating, :negotiating, :closed_won, :closed_lost, :dormant ]
end
```

My current attempts to show these on a "user dashboard":

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div id="chevrons">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#1">Prospect
              <span class="badge"><%= @user.sales_opportunities.count(:conditions => ":pipeline_status == 0") %></span>
          </a></li>
          <li><a href="#2">Qualifying
              <span class="badge"><%= @user.sales_opportunities.count(:conditions => ":pipeline_status == 1") %></span>
          </a></li>
          <li><a href="#3">Demonstrating
              <span class="badge"><%= @user.sales_opportunities.count(:conditions => ":pipeline_status == 2") %></span>
          </a></li>
          <li><a href="#4">Negotiating
            <span class="badge"><%= @user.sales_opportunities.count(:conditions => ":pipeline_status == 3") %></span>
          </a></li>
          <li><a href="#5">Closed
            <span class="badge", id="won"><%= @user.sales_opportunities.count(:conditions => ":pipeline_status == 4") %></span>
            <span class="badge", id="lost"><%= @user.sales_opportunities.count(:conditions => ":pipeline_status == 5") %></span>
          </a></li>
          <li id="dormant"><a href="#1">Dormant
          <span class="badge"><%= @user.sales_opportunities.count(:conditions => ":pipeline_status == 6") %></span>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: for clarity the current results of this page are to show each badge with the number one. I have only given this user one sales_opportunity (enum: "Prospect"), and it should register "1" for the "Prospect" chevron badge and "0" for all other chevron badges to work as I expect.

I was wondering whether I might need to extract this logic as a separate method call within either the Sales_Opportunity code or perhaps within a helper method, but figured there must be some way to get it working based on the standard Rails count feature. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` no longer accepts a conditions argument.  Use `where` instead. For example:

Replace:

```
@user.sales_opportunities.count(:conditions => ":pipeline_status == 1")
```

With:

```
@user.sales_opportunities.where(pipeline_status: 1).count
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks for your help. Why haven't they updated the documentation to reflect this? (maybe because lots of the docs are still about Rails 3?)

Comment: The [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count) have been updated.

Comment: Hmm, I got the idea to use :conditions from the docs I was reading yesterday. I guess that teaches me to be more vigilant on which version of the docs I'm working from. Thanks for your help in spotting my error anyway, I appreciate it greatly.